# не работает split по символу обратного слеша

Tags: javascript

выходит ошибка в строке где сплит с этим символом на деление выдает ошибку

```
(function () {
    var input = document.querySelector('.js-inputfile')
    var p = document.querySelector('.input-file-p')
    input.addEventListener('change', ()=>{
        input.value.split('\')
    })
})();
```

Comment: Дополните, пожалуйста: какой текст ошибки; что в `input.value`? Пробовали ли изолированно проверить, что проблема именно в `split`, а не где-то там еще? Если нет, попробуйте.

Comment: @mrEvgenX index.js:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token выдяляет символ \

Comment: @mrEvgenX например если использовать / то ошибки нету

Comment: Апостроф экранируется. Попробуйте '\\'

Comment: @mrEvgenX спасибо помогло, напишите как ответ, я его выберу

Comment: Сделайте поточнее заголовок? В духе "не работает split по символу обратного слеша", для потомков:) А то звучит, будто нашелся баг в среде исполнения JS

Comment: @mrEvgenX сделал:) подскажие, как можно поиск ближайшего элемента сделать, только не closest потому что он идет по предкам, мне нужно найти на одном уровне

Comment: Это уже новый вопрос, но может быть это поможет? https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator В остальном задавайте новый вопрос, тут нет смысла продолжать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Символ обратного слеша приводит к экранированию всего, что можно и нельзя.

Запись `'\'` обозначает строку без окончания, потому что одинарая кавычка экранирована.

Решение: экранировать экранирование.

`'\\'`

Comment:  лайк однозначно!